# Local mean filter in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a 512x512x512 numpy array. Is there any efficient way to perform a mean filter where every array value is substituted by all 3x3x3 local values?

We are seeking somethin similar to `scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter` but insted of median with mean.

Comment: `scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter`

Comment: We tried uniform_filter but from a complete positive matrix it give us some negative values. We don't know what exactly is doing.

Comment: What is the data type of the input array?  8-bit?

Comment: We used float 64 bit

Comment: If you have a reproducible example, you should report the issue to scipy: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve()` with a weight: `np.full((3, 3, 3), 1.0/27)`.

Answer (score 1):

mean filter is the alias of uniform filter, which is available in [`scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter.html)